# Stopping a user from running a program directly

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am writing an application in Qt which gets executed by a launcher app. How can I detect whether the Qt application was launched by the user or the launcher. Is command line parameters the only way or is there a better way?

Both the Qt app and launcher are written by me.

Comment: What are the security requirements? Do you just want to have the user to do the "right thing", or are you actually want to protect against malicious users?

Comment: For this project, I want the user to do the right thing. But I want something more complicated than simple command line parameters. I like the idea of using a named mutex, like mentioned in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of ways.  A command line parameter could be easily sniffed (by Process Explorer, e.g.), if that's a concern.  But a named mutex or some other interprocess handle that can be inherited by the child app would be more difficult to spoof.